# How can I be engaging the arduino mega with OBD-II UART card?

Tags: arduino-mega, uart

Currently I have been doing a project where I need to know the speed of the vehicle, I have implemented the following code but the results have not been good because when the vehicle is in motion always prints `STOPPED`.

I connected the OBDII-UART card from Sparkfun with Arduino MEGA.

The connection of the cards shown in the image attached below
[image: OBDII-UART -- ARDUINO MEGA]

```
  1.   char rxData[20];
  2.   char rxIndex = 0;
  3.   String inputString = "";
  4.   boolean stringComplete = false;
  5.   void setup(){
  6.   Serial.begin(9600);
  7.   Serial1.begin(9600);
  8.   Serial.flush();
  9.   Serial1.flush();
  10.   //Reset IC
  11.   Serial1.println("ATZ");
  12.   delay(1500);
  13.   getOBDResponse();
  14.   Serial.println(rxData);
  15.   clearBuffer();
  16.   getOBDResponse();
  17.   Serial.println(rxData);
  18.   clearBuffer();
  19.   //Sets IC to defults
  20.   Serial1.println("ATD");
  21.   delay(1000);
  22.   getOBDResponse();
  23.   Serial.println(rxData);
  24.   clearBuffer();
  25.   getOBDResponse();
  26.   Serial.println(rxData);
  27.   clearBuffer();
  28.   Serial1.println("ATSP0");
  29.   delay(1000);
  30.   getOBDResponse();
  31.   Serial.println(rxData);
  32.   clearBuffer();
  33.   getOBDResponse();
  34.   Serial.println(rxData);
  35.   clearBuffer();
  36.   Serial1.println("010D");
  37.   delay(1000);
  38.   getOBDResponse();
  39.   Serial.println(rxData);
  40.   clearBuffer();
  41.   getOBDResponse();
  42.   Serial.println(rxData);
  43.   clearBuffer();
  44.   Serial1.println("ATDP");
  45.   delay(1000);
  46.   getOBDResponse();
  47.   Serial.println(rxData);
  48.   clearBuffer();
  49.   getOBDResponse();
  50.   Serial.println(rxData);
  51.   clearBuffer();
  52.   //Bus initiation
  53.   Serial1.println("ATSI");
  54.   delay(3000);
  55.   getOBDResponse();
  56.   Serial.println(rxData);
  57.   clearBuffer();
  58.   getOBDResponse();
  59.   Serial.println(rxData);
  60.   clearBuffer();
  61.   Serial.flush();
  62.   Serial1.flush();
  63.   }
  64.   void loop(){
  65.   /*
  66.   if(stringComplete){
  67.   Serial.println(inputString);
  68.   inputString = "";
  69.   stringComplete = false;
  70.   }
  71.   */
  72.   Serial1.flush();
  73.   Serial1.println("010D");
  74.   getOBDResponse();
  75.   Serial.println(rxData);
  76.   clearBuffer();
  77.   getOBDResponse();
  78.   Serial.println(rxData);
  79.   clearBuffer();
  80.   }
  81.   void getOBDResponse(){
  82.   char inChar = 0;
  83.   while(inChar != '\r'){
  84.   if(Serial1.available() > 0){
  85.   if(Serial1.peek() == '\r'){
  86.   inChar = Serial1.read();
  87.   rxData[rxIndex] = '\0';
  88.   rxIndex = 0;
  89.   }else{
  90.   inChar = Serial1.read();
  91.   rxData[rxIndex++] = inChar;
  92.   }
  93.   }
  94.   }
  95.   }
  96.   void clearBuffer(){
  97.   int i;
  98.   for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  99.   rxData = '';
  100.   }
  101.   }
  102.   void serialEvent1(){
  103.   while(Serial1.available()){
  104.   char input = (char)Serial1.read();
  105.   inputString += input;
  106.   if(input == '\r'){
  107.   stringComplete = true;
  108.   }
  109.   }
```

I have based on the example is the page of the card https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/obd-ii-uart-hookup-guide/connecting-to-an-arduino, but when I set the protocol sends me Ok, but when I ask for the speed I send a message from Seeking I do not understand.Information truck tried to read from the console on a laptop

How can I accuratley get the speed of the car?

Well, now I require to get the speed I have entered the command according to the command table ELM327 I quickly attached.
[image: Parameter Identification]

Comment: I haven't studied the linked code in detail, but could you please add some more information? Comparing the example on the linked website (respectively on https://github.com/sparkfun/OBD-II_UART/blob/master/Firmware/obdIIUartQuickstart.ino), your commands are totally different. The linked sources send "010D" for vehicle speed and "010C" for RPM, what seems to make sense.

Comment: I have not achieved anything, still no answer card I tested with different cars but still showing me an error, someone who can help me please

Comment: Only was a baudios

Comment: On behalf of @Alejandro: I've been trying to make this circuit work but the only thing I am receiving after de 010D command is "SEARCHING......." "STOPPED" "SEARCHING......." "STOPPED" "SEARCHING......." "STOPPED". Do you experienced this problem? Or can you please share the code, bauds configuration, etc, that you used? Thanks in advance